# MATLAB - Displaying Data

Tags: matlab

So I am attempting to compute and display the average data as described in the attached picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2DHd.png) Here is what I have:

```
lakeData = load('C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\EGR2222\MATLAB\Data\LAKE_POWELL.txt');

year1= lakeData(:,1);
year2= lakeData (:,2);
year3= lakeData (:, 3);
year4= lakeData (:, 4);
year5= lakeData (:, 5);
year6= lakeData (:,6);
year7= lakeData (:,7);
year8= lakeData (:,8);

lakePowell = [year1, year2, year3, year4, year5, year6, year7, year8];
years = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007];
average = mean(lakePowell)

fprintf('The average water level was %s in %s\n', average, years)
```

My issue is that I am new to MATLAB and am not sure how to properly code my fprintf statement in order for it to print all the data at once. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want to loop through all values in `average` and all values in `years` and print them.

Also, you're going to want to use `%f` and `%d` for the formats since they are numbers.

```
for k = 1:numel(years)
    fprintf('The average water level was %f in %d\n', average(k), years(k))
end
```

Another option would be to concatenate `average` and `years` along the 1st dimension and then you can call `fprintf` once.

```
combined = cat(1, average(:).', years(:).');
fprintf('The average water level was %f in %d\n', combined);
```